# Make website HTTPS without having to change every link

Tags: c#, firefox, https, iis-7.5, query-string

I have an issue where firefox shows that my site is not secure in my login control.  My issue is that my website consists of two different URLS.  One is a public version and the other is a restricted version with login.  How can I make the restricted version urls all automatically use https so that all the user info is secure?

- I do have a valid certificate on this restricted server.
- I'm using IIS 7.5.7600
- I have use URL rewrite to redirect the login page, but I would like any
  url that points to this web server to use HTTPS.
- I do have a query string that points back to the page the users clicked
  "Login" on.

Comment: Two different URLs, two different websites or two different web servers? It's not clear at all.

Comment: Isn't just simpler (and more aligned with current security tendencies) to migrate the entire web site to HTTPS?

Comment: write a rewrite rule for restricted version URL  to go to https version. Use this - [https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/] on how to do that

Comment: It is two separate websites on the same web server.  They are independent but the links are inter-twined.      Should I make both websites redirect to https?  That shouldn't have any effect on links already being used by our users?   Thanks

Comment: ISHIDA, I'm getting a page not found on that URL you posted.